# how to dynamically add choices to a Symfony form EntityType element

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony6

I'm a Symfony novice developing a app (with Doctrine) to manage scheduling and billing for a psychology practice.

The entity `Invoice` has a one-to-many relationship with the entity`Session`. So my form class has an `EntityType` element and by default, Symfony fetches *all* the sessions in the database to populate the multiple select element. That's a lot of data I won't need and there is a nasty N+1 problem in addition (which I haven't yet figured out how to optimize away). What I want to do is *not* render this EntityType element at all and (obviously) not populate it with any options. Instead, the users selects the `Patient` entity from a dropdown, and then via an xhr call we fetch the sessions that belong to that patient and that are not yet associated with any invoice -- a much smaller amount of data -- and render the options as checkboxes. So, in the form class:

```php
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
        {
            $builder
                ->add('invoice_date', DateType::class, ['widget'=>'single_text',])
                ->add('payer',HiddenType::class)
                ->add('sessions',null, [
                    // this does not solve N+1
                    /*'query_builder'=>function(SessionRepository $repository)
                    {return $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')->leftJoin('s.invoice','invoice')
                        ->join('s.patients','patients')
                        ->leftJoin('patients.payer','payer')
                        ->andWhere('s.invoice is null')
                        ->addSelect('patients','payer');},
                    */
                    // ...but with this, it does not assign our input to the form
                    'choices'=>[],
                ])
                ->add('patient',EntityType::class,[
                    'placeholder'=>'',
                    'class'=>Patient::class,
                    'mapped'=>false,
                    'constraints' =>[
                        new Assert\NotBlank(['message'=>'patient is required']),
                    ],
                    'query_builder'=>$this->accountService->getActivePatientQueryBuilder(),
                    'choice_attr' => function($patient){
                        $payer = $patient->getPayer();
                        return $payer === null ? [] :[
                            'data-payer_id'=>$payer->getId(),
                           
                        ];
                    },
                ])
                // other elements etc omitted for brevity

            ;
        }
    }
```

When I do let Symfony populate the Sessions/EntityType element with choices, everything works but the excess query problem remains. When I do it my way, i.e., defining the choices key as an empty array and dynamically adding choices to the form, it looks like it should work, but Symfony complains with the validation error "The selected choice is invalid" and does not assign the submitted values to the element. Looking at the Exception message in the profiler we see

> The choices "4714", "4743", "4772", "4801", "4830", "4859", "4888",
> "4917", "4946" do not exist in the choice list.

Fair enough. So the question is:  how do I add these choices to my EntityType element after the form is submitted?

I have read about EventListeners in the documentation, and `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` looks like a good event to hook into. But after much wrestling with this, nothing is working and I can't find anything about this in the documentation.

Another possible solution that should work is to do this as a two-step thing where first they choose the patient, then I dynamically render a form with the candidate sessions filtered down to the ones belonging to that patient and not associated with an invoice. But I
am stubborn and want to make Symfony let this element accept my data.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is *the* answer, but it is an answer. I'd like to think there is some way to change the EntityType element's 'choices' option directly, but if there is, I couldn't figure it out. So I set an event listener to overwrite the 'sessions' EntityType element with a new one (by the same name) whose options (choices) are the same as the data submitted by the user. It feels a little like changing a light bulb by holding the light bulb still and rotating the house. The good news is that it works -- for creating a new Invoice entity. Updating is a different story, which I haven't gotten to yet.

```php
class InvoiceFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(private AccountService $accountService)
    {
      // AccountService is a class that does some heavy lifting and it
      // has an EntityManager
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('invoice_date', DateType::class, ['widget'=>'single_text',])
            ->add('payer',HiddenType::class)
            ->add('sessions',null, [
                'label'=>'Sessions',
                'choices'=>[],
                ]
            )
            ->add('patient',EntityType::class,[
                'placeholder'=>'',
                'class'=>Patient::class,
                'mapped'=>false,
                'constraints' =>[
                    new Assert\NotBlank(['message'=>'patient is required']),
                ],
                'query_builder'=>$this->accountService->getActivePatientQueryBuilder(),
                'choice_attr' => function($patient){
                    $payer = $patient->getPayer();
                    return $payer === null ? [] :[
                        'data-payer_id'=>$payer->getId(),
                    ];
                },
            ])
            // more elements omitted for brevity, then...

            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,[$this,'onPreSubmit'])
        ;

        $builder->get('payer')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            // outgoing
            function($entity){ return $entity ? $entity->getId() : null; },
            // incoming
            function($id){
                return $id ? $this->accountService->getEntityManager()->find(Person::class,$id) : null;
            },
        ));
    }

    // here's the interesting bit that handles our issue
    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event) : void
    {
        $form_data = $event->getData();
        $ids = $form_data['sessions'];
        $payer_id = $form_data['payer'];
        $sessions = $this->accountService->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            "SELECT s FROM App\Entity\Session s 
            -- might as well sanity-check the sessions while we're here
            LEFT JOIN s.invoice invoice
            JOIN s.payer payer
            WHERE s.id IN (:ids) AND s.invoice IS NULL
            AND payer.id = :payer_id"
        )->setParameters(['ids'=>$ids,'payer_id'=>$payer_id])->getResult();

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('sessions',EntityType::class,[
            'class'=>Session::class,
            'multiple'=>true,
            'choices' => $sessions,
            'by_reference'=>false,// <-- you do NOT want to forget this
        ]);
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Invoice::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better idea, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unresolved issue, see work around here. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/42451#issuecomment-1049069268

Kinda, ugly but it works!

It used to work using the ->resetViewTransformers() Method on the field:

```
->add('myField', ChoiceType::class,[
    'label' => 'My Field',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
])
->get('myField')->resetViewTransformers()
```